# How to get row data through angular material menu inside ag-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, ag-grid

I've a requirement where in ag-grid, I need to open a menu to add/edit/delete that row data. I'm using angular material menu component as cell template url. but when click on that menu item, it does not trigger onCellClicked event in ag-grid to get reference to clicked row data however If I click pixels away from menu item then event is fired. 
Need help to figure out, how can I get row data on menu click.

my ag-grid code goes here:

```
var columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "", field: "icon", width:65},
    {headerName: "Categories",field:"category_name", width:1025, cellRenderer:function(params){
    // my cell renderer code goes here
      },
   onCellClicked:function(params){
      console.log("Cell is still getting click "+params.data);
  //This click does not work
    },

    {headerName: "", field: "options", width:87, suppressMenu: true, templateUrl:"partials/options.html"
  }
];
```

options.html

```
<md-menu>
  <!-- <md-button aria-label="Open phone interactions menu" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="openMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event)">
    <md-icon md-svg-src="images/icons/options.svg" aria-label="android "></md-icon>
  </md-button> -->
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="option-btn" ng-click="openMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event)">options</a>
  <md-menu-content width="4">
    <md-menu-item>
      <md-button ng-click="modifyOptions($event)">
        <md-icon md-svg-src="images/icons/add.svg" aria-label="android "></md-icon>
        Add
      </md-button>
    </md-menu-item>
    <md-menu-item>
      <md-button ng-click="toggleNotifications()">
        <md-icon md-svg-src="images/icons/edit.svg" aria-label="android "></md-icon>
        Edit
      </md-button>
    </md-menu-item>
    <md-menu-divider></md-menu-divider>
    <md-menu-item>
      <md-button disabled="disabled" ng-click="checkVoicemail()">
        <md-icon md-svg-src="images/icons/delete.svg" aria-label="android "></md-icon>
        Delete
      </md-button>
    </md-menu-item>
  </md-menu-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for my question which was not pretty hard though: Cell template has reference to data object for each row, so property can be accessed by calling `data.your_property`. Here I didn't need onCellClicked event at all. Below is working code:

```
var columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "", field: "icon", width:65},
    {headerName: "Categories",field:"category_name", width:1025, cellRenderer:function(params){

      // Cell Renderer goes here
},

    {headerName: "", field: "options", width:87, suppressMenu: true, templateUrl:"partials/options.html"
  }
];
```

option.html

```
<md-menu>

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="option-btn" ng-    click="openMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event, **data**)">options</a>
<md-menu-content width="4">
<md-menu-item>
  <md-button ng-click="modifyOptions($event, data)">
    <md-icon md-svg-src="images/icons/add.svg" aria-label="android "></md-icon>
    Add
  </md-button>
</md-menu-item>
<md-menu-item>
  <md-button ng-click="modifyCategory(data)">
    <md-icon md-svg-src="images/icons/edit.svg" aria-label="android "></md-icon>
    Edit
  </md-button>
</md-menu-item>
<md-menu-divider></md-menu-divider>
<md-menu-item>
  <md-button disabled="disabled" ng-click="deleteCategory(data)">
    <md-icon md-svg-src="images/icons/delete.svg" aria-label="android "></md-icon>
    Delete
  </md-button>
</md-menu-item>
```

Comment: I have the same problem can you please copy how you called the cellRenderer gets called I really would appreciate it